# MySQL: funciones y la forma de capturar errores

Tags: mysql, funciones

Siguiendo la línea de mi otro post ([mi otro post](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/557348/funciones-en-mysql-o-funciones-en-php)), y habiendo leído y buscado por internet, no encuentro la forma de capturar los errores dentro de la función en MySQL.
Pongamos este ejemplo:

```
delimiter //

drop function if exists Nuevo_Cliente //
create function Nuevo_Cliente(rsocial varchar(50), ncomercial varchar(50), cuit varchar(15), cfinal tinyint, direccion longtext, observaciones longtext) returns int
begin

    declare exit handler for sqlexception
    begin
        return 0;
    end;

    insert ignore into clientes (razon_social, nombre_comercial, cuit, es_consumidor_final, direccion, observaciones, fecha_alta) values (rsocial, ncomercial, cuit, cfinal, direccion, observaciones, now());
    return last_insert_id();

end //

delimiter ;
```

Lo que busco es que en caso de que haya cualquier clase de error/excepción/aviso que no permita un insert exitoso poder devolver un valor. Cómo sería posible hacerlo en MySQL?

Gracias!

**Ampliación (19/9/22):**

Esta es la función:

```
create function Nuevo_Cliente(rsocial varchar(50), ncomercial varchar(50), cuit varchar(15), cfinal tinyint, direccion longtext, observaciones longtext) returns int
begin
    declare cant int;
    declare mensaje longtext;
    
     declare exit handler for sqlexception 
         begin
         set mensaje = concat("Error en el alta\ncant = ", cant, "\nR. Social = ", rsocial, "\nN. Comercial = ", ncomercial, "\nCUIT = ", cuit, "\nC. Final = ", cfinal, "\nDir = ", direccion, "\nObs. = ", observaciones);
         signal sqlstate '45004' set MESSAGE_TEXT = mensaje;
         return 4;
     end;
    
    set cant = 0;
    select count(id) into cant from clientes where razon_social = rsocial;
    if (cant != 0) then
        set mensaje = concat("La razón social '", rsocial, "' ya existe: cant = " , cant);
        signal sqlstate '45001' set MESSAGE_TEXT = mensaje;
        return 1;
    end if;
    
    set cant = 0;
    select count(id) into cant from clientes where nombre_comercial = ncomercial;
    if (cant != 0) then
        set mensaje = concat("El nombre comercial '", ncomercial, "' ya existe: cant = " , cant);
        signal sqlstate '45002' set MESSAGE_TEXT = mensaje;
        return 2;
    end if;
    
    set cant = 0;    
    select count(id) into cant from clientes where cuit = cuit;
    if (cant != 0) then 
        set mensaje = concat("El C.U.I.T. '", cuit, "' ya existe: cant = " , cant);
        signal sqlstate '45003' set MESSAGE_TEXT = mensaje;
        return 3;
    end if;
    
    
    insert into clientes (razon_social, nombre_comercial, cuit, es_consumidor_final, direccion, observaciones, fecha_alta) values (rsocial, ncomercial, cuit, cfinal, direccion, observaciones, now());
    
    signal sqlstate '45000' set MESSAGE_TEXT = "Alta correcta";
    
    return 0;
end //
```

Sin embargo el comportamiento no es el esperado. El CUIT puede validarlo o no, no consigo determinar cuándo si o cuándo no. Y el insert generalmente da error aunque los valores sean válidos. Esta es la tabla:

```
+---------------------+-------------+------+-----+------------------+----------------+
| Field               | Type        | Null | Key | Default          | Extra          |
+---------------------+-------------+------+-----+------------------+----------------+
| id                  | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL             | auto_increment |
| razon_social        | varchar(50) | NO   |     | Consumidor final |                |
| nombre_comercial    | varchar(50) | NO   |     | Consumidor final |                |
| cuit                | varchar(15) | YES  |     | NULL             |                |
| es_consumidor_final | tinyint(4)  | NO   |     | 1                |                |
| direccion           | longtext    | YES  |     | NULL             |                |
| observaciones       | longtext    | YES  |     | NULL             |                |
| fecha_alta          | datetime    | NO   |     | NULL             |                |
+---------------------+-------------+------+-----+------------------+----------------+
```

Gracias.

Comment: Los `HANDLER` trabajan con los códigos de error. Por ejemplo si pones esto: `DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR 1062` y luego esto: `SELECT 'Error, duplicate key occurred';`, cuando haya un error de clave duplicada (código de error `1062`) el procedimiento almacenado se detendrá de inmediato y arrojará el mensaje `Error, duplicate key occurred`. Para más detalles revisa [este tutorial](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-error-handling-in-stored-procedures/) así como [la doc del MR](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/declare-handler.html).

Comment: Si, había leído sobre cómo manejar errores puntuales. Yo busco un símil de `try...catch`. He leído que no existe en MySQL. Quiero implementar algo genérico que atrape cualquier cosa que no permita un insert exitoso y la función pueda devolver un código cuando el insert no es exitoso. No importa por qué (ahora).

Comment: ah, mira! no había visto ese enlace. Por lo que he leído por encima, puedo declarar varios exit handlers. Igual quiero algo genérico.

Comment: No existe `try ... catch`, lo que podrías hacer sería recoger todos los códigos de error que impedirían un `INSERT`, tales como: clave duplicada, nombre de columna erróneo, violación de alguna restricción, etc y manejar dichos códigos de error emitiendo un código único (personalizado) para todos los casos o bien usar [`SIGNAL Statement`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/signal.html).

Comment: Un snippet único requiere mucho tiempo, líneas de código y revisiones conforme a cada actualización. Voy a leer bien en detalle acerca de `signal statement`y volveré con mis conclusiones. Parece prometedor.

Comment: Habiendo leído y realizado algunas pruebas con `signal statement`, no consigo escribir la función que funcione. En el post original añadí una ampliación con la nueva función. @A.Cedano